# How to share memory in cluster machine (qsub openmpi)

Tags: cluster-computing, openmpi, qsub

dear all！

I have a question about sharing memory in cluster. I am a new to cluster, and fail to solve my problem after trying about several weeks, so I look for help here, any suggestion would be grateful!

I want to use soapdenovo, a software that was used to assemble human genome to assemble my data. However, it failed in one step because shortage of memory (the memory is 512G in my machine). So I turned to cluster machine (which have three big nodes, each node have 512 memory too), and started to learn submit job with qsub. Considering that one node couldn't solve my problem, I googled and found that openmpi may help, but when I running openmpi with demo data, it seemed it only run the command several times. Then I found to use openmpi, the software must include library of openmpi, and I didn't know whether soapdenovo is support openmpi, I had asked the question but the author didn't give me answer yet. Suppose soapdenovo support the openmpi, how should I solve my problem. If it didn't support openmpi, can I use memory in different nodes to run the software?

The problem had tortured my so much, thanks for any help. Following is what had I do and some information about the cluster machine:

1. Install openmpi and submit the job

1) The script of job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y
#$ -S /bin/bash
#

export PATH=/tools/openmpi/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tools/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
soapPath="/tools/SOAPdenovo2/SOAPdenovo-63mer"
workPath="/NGS"
outputPath="assembly/soap/demo"
/tools/openmpi/bin/mpirun $soapPath all -s $workPath/$outputPath/config_file -K 23 -R -F -p 60 -V -o $workPath/$outputPath/graph_prefix > $workPath/$outputPath/ass.log 2> $workPath/$outputPath/ass.err
```

2) Submit the job:

```
qsub -pe orte 60 mpi.qsub
```

3) The log in ass.err

a) It seemed it run soapdenovo several times according to the log

```
cat ass.err | grep "Pregraph" | wc -l
60
```

b) detail information

```
less ass.err (it seemed it only run soapdenov several times, because when I run it in my machine, it would only output one Pregraph):


Version 2.04: released on July 13th, 2012
Compile Apr 27 2016     15:50:02

********************
Pregraph
********************

Parameters: pregraph -s /NGS/assembly/soap/demo/config_file -K 23 -p 16 -R -o /NGS/assembly/soap/demo/graph_prefix 

In /NGS/assembly/soap/demo/config_file, 1 lib(s), maximum read length 35, maximum name length 256.


Version 2.04: released on July 13th, 2012
Compile Apr 27 2016     15:50:02

********************
Pregraph
********************

and so on
```

c) information of stdin

```
cat ass.log:

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING: A process refused to die despite all the efforts!
This process may still be running and/or consuming resources.

Host: smp03
PID:  75035

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpirun noticed that process rank 58 with PID 0 on node c0214.local exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault).
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

2. Information about cluster:

1) qconf -sql

```
all.q
smp.q
```

2) qconf -spl

```
mpi
mpich
orte
zhongxm
```

3) qconf -sp zhongxm

```
pe_name            zhongxm
slots              999
user_lists         NONE
xuser_lists        NONE
start_proc_args    /bin/true
stop_proc_args     /bin/true
allocation_rule    $fill_up
control_slaves     TRUE
job_is_first_task  FALSE
urgency_slots      min
accounting_summary FALSE
```

4) qconf -sq smp.q

```
qname                 smp.q
hostlist              @smp.q
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       np_load_avg=1.75
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:05:00
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:05:00
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               make zhongxm
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 1
tmpdir                /tmp
shell                 /bin/csh
prolog                NONE
epilog                NONE
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant
starter_method        NONE
suspend_method        NONE
resume_method         NONE
terminate_method      NONE
notify                00:00:60
owner_list            NONE
user_lists            NONE
xuser_lists           NONE
subordinate_list      NONE
complex_values        NONE
projects              NONE
xprojects             NONE
calendar              NONE
initial_state         default
s_rt                  INFINITY
h_rt                  INFINITY
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_stack               INFINITY
h_stack               INFINITY
s_core                INFINITY
h_core                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                INFINITY
```

5) qconf -sq all.q

```
qname                 all.q
hostlist              @allhosts
seq_no                0
load_thresholds       np_load_avg=1.75
suspend_thresholds    NONE
nsuspend              1
suspend_interval      00:05:00
priority              0
min_cpu_interval      00:05:00
processors            UNDEFINED
qtype                 BATCH INTERACTIVE
ckpt_list             NONE
pe_list               make zhongxm
rerun                 FALSE
slots                 16,[c0219.local=32]
tmpdir                /tmp
shell                 /bin/csh
prolog                NONE
epilog                NONE
shell_start_mode      posix_compliant
starter_method        NONE
suspend_method        NONE
resume_method         NONE
terminate_method      NONE
notify                00:00:60
owner_list            NONE
user_lists            mobile
xuser_lists           NONE
subordinate_list      NONE
complex_values        NONE
projects              NONE
xprojects             NONE
calendar              NONE
initial_state         default
s_rt                  INFINITY
h_rt                  INFINITY
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_stack               INFINITY
h_stack               INFINITY
s_core                INFINITY
h_core                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                INFINITY
```

Comment: lam, do `ldd /tools/SOAPdenovo2/SOAPdenovo-63mer` (if it is real ELF binary file) to find out is there any libmpi linked to application. To use MPI application must be written with use of MPI calls and compiled with your version of MPI library (OpenMPI, not MPICH).

Answer (score 0):

According to https://hpc.unt.edu/soapdenovo the software doesn't support MPI:

> This code is NOT compiled with MPI, and should only be used in parallel on a SINGLE node, via a threaded model.

So, you can't just start the software with mpiexec on cluster to have access to more memory. Cluster machines are connected with non-coherent networks (Ethernet, Infiniband) which are slower than memory bus, and PCs in cluster do not share their memory. Clusters use MPI libraries (OpenMPI or MPICH) to work with network, and all requests between nodes is explicit: program calls MPI_Send in one process and MPI_Recv in other. There are also one-way calls like MPI_Put/MPI_Get to access remote memory (RDMA - remote direct memory access), but this is not the same as local memory.

Comment: Hi, osgx, thanks for your reply, and I some new questions list blow, could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

osgx, thank you for your reply very much and sorry for the delay of this message.

Since I don't major in computer, I think I can't understand some glossary very well, like ELF. So there are some new questions and I list my question as follow, thanks for help advace:

1) When I "ldd SOAPdenovo-63mer", it outputed "not a dynamic executable", did this mean "the code is not complied with MPI" that you mentioned?

2) In short, I can't solve the problem with the cluster, and I have to look for a machine with more than 512G memory?

3) Also, I used another software called ALLPATHS-LG (http://www.broadinstitute.org/software/allpaths-lg/blog/) that was also failed for shortage of memory, and according to FAQ C1 (http://www.broadinstitute.org/software/allpaths-lg/blog/?page_id=336), what "it uses share memory parallelization" mean, did it means it can use memory in cluster, or only memory in a node, and I have to find a machine with enough memory?

```
C1. Can I run ALLPATHS-LG on a cluster?
You can, but it will only use one machine, not the entire cluster.  That machine would need to have enough memory to fit the entire assembly. ALLPATHS-LG does not support distributed computing using MPI, instead it uses Shared Memory Parallelization.
```

By the way, this is first time I posted here, I think I should use commit to reply, considering so many words, I use "Answer Your Question".

Comment: 1)  this means that 63mer is probably script, and ldd will work only for real ELF file of application. 2) Yes (or ask authors of the SOAPdenovo directly or using mail list) 3) Yes, "use one machine" is about thread parallelisation, not cluster APIs like MPI/PGAS.

Comment: lam, how long will program run? There may be other option of extending memory which will make run much longer - add big SSD disk as swap. Application will be able to use more memory, but when working set is >512GB, there will be a lot of slow page faults (swap page out, swap page in). SSD is very bad in writing, but just ~100-1000 times worse than memory in reading.

Comment: lam, in case of short run you may also try some cloud servers, but the cost of high mem servers is very high, and you can spend 100s of dollars in a day from your credit card. For example, AWS has x1.32xlarge with ~2 TB of mem with ~15$ per hour for cpu rent in ondemand.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! It is about 4 days of this program, I think I have to look for cloud servers, or try to reduce my data. Also, I google with a software called vSMP (http://www.scalemp.com/products/vsmp-foundation-free/) which may be hlep! Thanks again!

Comment: lam, vSMP may be able to emulate bigger memory machine from cluster machines, but: in free version no more than 1 TB RAM (two nodes of 0.5TB RAM); and there is still slow network between nodes (usually, memory access is cheaper than network access, even with Infiniband), and access to memory from other node probably will be handled as page fault (addtional cost of interrupt and network access par page)

Comment: Hi, osgx! I guess 800G RAM would enough for me, and 1) what does "two nodes of 0.5TB RAM" mean, Considering I have three nodes that each have 512G memory, can I use vSMP to achieve 1TB RAM? 2) Did I have to be root to use vSMP? 3) I don't know how nodes were connected, I think it would be Ethernet, and I don't carry about the speed as long as it can finished in two weeks, so do you think vSMP would help? In fact, the cluster I used belong to another school, and the  administrate is major in biology too, we have little knowledge about cluster, we are very grateful for everything you helped!

Comment: Also, I can't find setting that would email me when there are reply, so I just refresh the web to see if you had reply, so there would be some delay for my reply......

Comment: lam, not two, but "three big nodes, each node have 512 memory too" as you said. You may try vSMP, but it will run only on some supported hardware, not on other. vSMP needs rebooting computers into custom hypervisor, it not root access, it should be physical access to nodes (contact their stuff to experiment with vSMP). To get info about connections, do `lspci` command and search for Network controllers (Mellanox for Infiniband). Can you split your task into several smaller tasks, it will be more convenient way to done?

Comment: Hi, osgx! I would try vSMP could help. It is a pity that the cluster is supervised by us, and no one have a lot of knowledge in computer, so I have to try by myself......According to the menu of SOAPdenovo and ALLPATHS-LG, I think it couldn't split the work to several small jobs.  When type lspci | grep -i network, it is Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection, so it wouldn't be Infiniband, am I right?